# How to check if an application is part of a keychain entry's ACL?

Tags: macos, acl, keychain

I'm new to Mac development and the keychain concepts. I wish to obtain some clarity on the topics, but I do have a specific question.

I have an app that is privately distributed, not through the app store. My signing certificate changed earlier, so now we have an old app and a new app. They have the same bundle id and filesystem path, but the new app gives a prompt when trying to access keychain entries created by the old app. I need to run this remotely so prompts are not acceptable.

I realised after some research that editing the ACL for the old keychain entries is not possible without giving a prompt, so I've instead decided to delete those keychain entries if and only if the new app does not have access to them. This has to be determined by the installer, which is a third app unrelated to the old or new app.

How do I check if a given application is in a keychain entry's access control list?

Here is the approach I tried: I used `SecACLCopyContents` on the `SecKeychainItemRef` to get the array of `SecTrustedApplicationRef`s.

I then used `SecTrustedApplicationCreateFromPath` to get a `SecTrustedApplicationRef` for the new app.

I then iterated over the array of `SecTrustedApplicationRef` and compared their results of `SecTrustedApplicationCopyData` to check if any app matches the one I created from the path.

However, I get a match for any two apps as long as they have the same filesystem path, even if they have completely different content. I have probably misunderstood the purpose of `SecTrustedApplicationRef` and `SecTrustedApplicationCopyData`.

TL;DR

What is the correct approach to check if some application has access to a keychain entry made long ago? Given that we cannot assume that bundle id and filesystem path are unique identifiers for the contents of the app.

Bonus question: What does security actually compare to determine if an app has permission to access a keychain entry?

Comment: I am facing the problem while reading the ACL list of a keychain Item, is it possible for you to share the link or code to get the ACL using `SecACLCopyContents` ?